# Phpmyadmin doesn't work if session.save_handler set to memcache

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Phpmyadmin doesn't work if session.save_handler set to memcache. as soon as I login I get `your session has expired, please login again`

php.ini

```
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path = "tcp://localhost:11211"
```

I tried the latest version available from 
http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php

Comment: "Doesn't work" Thank you for giving enough information. What do you mean by "doesn't work" ?

Comment: @DarylGill as soon as I login I get you session has expired, please login again

Comment: having the same problem with phpmyadmin 4.1.2: as soon as I log in, I am redirected back to the login page but without an error message or so, just the plain login page.

Comment: 4.6.3 and same. `Catchable Fatal Error in .\libraries\session.‌​lib.php#20 session_regenerate_i‌​d(): Failed to create(read) session ID: memcache (path: tcp://127.0.0.1:1121‌​1?persistent=1&amp;am‌​p;weight=1&amp;amp;ti‌​meout=1&amp;amp;retry‌​_interval=15) Backtrace .\libraries\session.‌​lib.php#20: session_regenerate_i‌​d(boolean true) .\libraries\common.i‌​nc.php#734: PMA_secureSession() .\index.php#13: require_once(.\libra‌​ries\common.inc.php)`. Also happens with Adminer.

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same problem here... After I enabled memcache session handling in PHP, I can't connect anymore to *phpmyadmin*. It's due to incompatibility between *phpmyadmin* own session handling mechanism and memcache.

You can disable memcache session handling by putting at the top of your *phpmyadmin* `config.inc.php`:

```
ini_set('session.save_path', '');
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
```

cf. http://thinkfuturetechs.blogspot.fr/2014/06/phpmyadmin-and-memcache.html

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been a server misconfiguration issue; from the bug report on the phpMyAdmin issue tracker a reporter wrote that memcached was missing. Check that memcached is properly installed and configured. You can see the bug report at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/10464

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13359932)

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas sure, that makes sense, but at the time I posted this (three years ago), there was no *resolution* to the bug report, just an issue that was reported to the development team. There wasn't anything else to put here, other than that it appeared to be an issue that was experienced by someone else and was pending a fix by the development team (though the reporter ended up being the same as the poster here and the problem appears to be a server misconfiguration rather than software bug). I'm just not sure what more I could have wrote *at the time*, but have enhanced the answer now.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas Anyway, I have tried to improve my answer here and hope this edit helps. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I believe so. Just I got this in my review.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce your problem with the same settings as yours. I have memcached running and the memcache extension installed. Tested with phpMyAdmin 4.0.6 and 4.1-dev.

Answer (score 0):

With phpMyAdmin 4.7 and memcached it works if you add one line to libraries/common.inc

```
ini_set('session.save_path', '127.0.0.1:11211');
```

the issue at my installation was having more than one memcached server

Remember: using memcached no tcp:// using memcache use tcp:// in front of your memcached Server IP

Comment: No doubt you don't have session.save_handler set so you're not actually using memcache.

Comment: Works. And is the correct solution when using the php extension memcached (note the ending 'd')

Answer (score -1):

You might have to change this lines in phpmyadmin folder **`'libraries/session.inc.php'`**:

Try include this line at the top of the file:

```
ini_set('session.save_path', "/tmp/");
```

Uncomment this line (**about 74**):

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
```

Comment: it beats the purpose of using memcache. I want phpmyadmin to work with memcache handler, not with files.